# MSI MS7269 - Video controller Driver

Tags: drivers, motherboard

Have you seen any driver for this motherboard's Graphics ?

Answer (score 1):

Can't find that model directly from the MSI site, however I did find this:

http://www.motherboards.org/mobot/motherboards_d/MSI/915GLM2-V+%2528MS-7269%2529/

Which links the number you give to this mother board driver link:

http://www.msi.com/index.php?func=downloaddetail&type=driver&maincat_no=1&prod_no=268